# Is calling request.getSession(true) explicitly required to persist programmatic authentication via request.login(username,password)?

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, servlet-filters

While working on a Java Servlet `Filter` to integrate with an internal SSO I struggled to find the correct way to create a persistent login using programmatic security functions. Specifically, after reading many tutorials such as [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjiie.html) I was calling `request.login(username,password)` and a user `Principal` was created that returned correct values for methods `request.isUserInRole(role)` etc. for the current request.

I expected this to be persistent for the user, but subsequent requests would return `null` for `request.getUserPrincipal()` so my authentication code was entered on every request. What I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22042537/3357118) after much searching was that calling `request.getSession(true)` before calling `request.login(username,password)` causes the `Principal` to be persistent for the user session.

Is it required to explicitly create a session *before* logging the user in to persist the `Principal` for the session? This behaviour seems odd to me so I am wondering if I am doing something wrong. I appreciate any insight from developers more knowledgeable on the matter than myself. Using JDK 7 and Tomcat 8. Realm is an extension of RealmBase that overrides authenticate(username,password), getName(), getPassword(username) and getPrincipal(username).

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain fc) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest  request  = (HttpServletRequest)req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse)res;

    if(request.getUserPrincipal() == null) {
        try {
            String userName = request.getParameter(userNameField);
            String password = request.getParameter(passwordField);

            request.getSession(true); // <-- block always entered without this

            request.login(username,password);
         }
         catch(ServletException e) {
             // Handle failed login...
             return;
         }
    }

    fc.doFilter(req,res);
}
```

Comment: The session needs to be created first because that's where the Principal is put. You could make a case that request.login() should do that for you, but evidently it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks. That gets to the root of the matter. I find it odd that it automatically stores it there _if_ the session exists. I originally had the two lines reversed (I was creating the session right after login) which was the same as not creating one at all. I probably should look at the RealmBase code...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the Tomcat source for `AuthenticatorBase.java` where the `login(username,password)` chaining calls the configured `Realm's` `authenticate(username,password)` method and then calls `register(...)` passing the returned `Principal` and stores it in a session if one exists.